# Extended Permissions on Facebook Graph API in PHP

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to write an app using the most recent Facebook PHP SDK. However, any extended permissions I request are simply not requested, it always defaults to the basic request, and does not ask for any of the requested extended permissions.

Here is how I am requesting these permissions:

```
<?php 
require_once("facebook.php");

$app_id = "xxx";
$app_secret = "xxx";

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId' => $app_id,
    'secret' => $app_secret,
    'cookie' => true
));

if(is_null($facebook->getUser())){
    $params = array(‘scope’ => ‘user_status,publish_stream,user_photos’);       
    header("Location:{$facebook->getLoginUrl($params)}");
    exit;
}
?>
```

This file is included at the beginning of any page on which my app is embedded. Any ideas as to why I don't get the extended permissions I want?

Comment: Is the request parameter not 'scope' rather than 'req_perm'?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure you are using quotes `'`. It seems that you copied this example from a page or something.

```
if(is_null($facebook->getUser())){
    $params = array('req_perms' => 'user_status,publish_stream,user_photos');
    header("Location:{$facebook->getLoginUrl($params)}");
    exit;
}
```

---

**UPDATE:** use `scope` instead of `req_perms` with the new SDK.

Comment: Durr. I has having some issues, and then copied/pasted some code to try and eliminate my errors. It turns out this was not the best protocol. Sometimes, I just don't see the obvious. Thanks!

Comment: @CoreyLarson: Happens to all of us my friend! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the 'scope' parameter in a **comma separated** array.